# Dhcp-server ignoring MAC address of host declaration in dhcpd.conf

Tags: dhcp

I would like some help interpreting what is happening on my firewall/dhcp-server host.

I've built a new firewall and used the dchpd.conf script from the old firewall.  The script contains several host declarations of the form:

```
host_name {
   hardware ethernet ab:cd:ef:01:23:45;
   fixed-address 192.168.0.133;
}
```

When I look at the dhcpd.leases file, the lease record with IP address 192.168.0.133 shows a different value after `hardware ethernet` than the dhcpd.conf host declaration. This problem is causing problems with IP address contentions and failed connections with Minecraft and other local servers (a problem I know I can fix by having that host set a fixed address from the pool reserved for that kind of address).

In trying to fix this, I've learned that there is another value, dhcp-client-identifier, associated with hosts.  Perhaps that is the unfamiliar value in dhcpd.leases, but I don't know how to confirm that.

Can someone direct me to the documentation that covers this?  I've studied the dhcpd.conf man page and found no clues.

Debian Bullseye on NanoPi R5S, isc-dhcp-server version 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's cos the man is just a manual for *nixs :)

What you need to check out is the standard, which should be [RFC-4361](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4361). For v4 behaviur @ 6.1 you'll see that the recommendation is to not only rely on MACs, but also use an identifier. So what you read should be valid in this case, or at least, that's how I interpret it. I didn't face your scenario yet so I can't really test it. Try it out and let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  While I respect the issues raised in the standard, they are not a problem in my small, non-IOT-enabled home LAN.

In fact,  I would be happy to use any stable unique device identifier.  The problem here is that the only way to find the device identifier is by looking at the dhcpd.leases file.  The MAC address is convenient because I can pick up, for example, my son's IPad and read its MAC address in the settings.  My 10-year-old inkjet printer has a MAC address, but its lease uses a derived address.  Will that derived address always be the same?